# SQL Cursor w/Stored Procedure versus Query with UDF

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, cursors

I'm trying to optimize a stored procedure I'm maintaining, and am wondering if anyone can clue me in to the performance benefits/penalities of the options below.  For my solution, I basically need to run a conversion program on an image stored in an IMAGE column in a table.  The conversion process lives in an external .EXE file.  Here are my options:

1. Pull the results of the target table into a temporary table, and then use a cursor to go over each row in the table and run a stored procedure on the IMAGE column.  The stored proc calls out to the .EXE.
2. Create a UDF that calls the .EXE file, and run a SQL query similar to "select UDFNAME(Image_Col) from TargetTable".

I guess what I'm looking for is an idea of how much overhead would be added by the creation of the cursor, instead of doing it as a set?

Some additional info:

- The size of the set in this case is max. 1000
- As an answer mentions below, if done as a set with a UDF, will that mean that the external program is opened 1000 times all at once?  Or are there optimizations in place for that?  Obviously, on a multi-processor system, it may not be a bad thing to have multiple instances of the process running, but 1000 might be a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little testing and experimenting, and when done in a UDF, it does indeed process each row at a time - SQL server doesn't run 100 processes for each of the 100 rows (I didn't think it would).

However, I still believe that doing this as a UDF instead of as a cursor would be better, because my research tends to show that the extra overhead of having to pull the data out in the cursor would slow things down.  It may not make a huge difference, but it might save time versus pulling all of the data out into a temporary table first.

Answer (score 1):

define set base in this context? 
If you have 100 rows will this open up the app 100 times in one shot?  I would say test and just because you can call an extended proc from a UDF I would still use a cursor for this because setbased doesn't matter in this case since you are not manipulating data in the tables directly